# How to solve the following question from complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\alpha=e^{\frac{i2\pi}{7}}$ and $f(x)= a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{20} a_kx^k$ then the value of $$f(x)+f(\alpha x)+f(\alpha^2 x)+\cdots+f(\alpha^6 x)$$ is $ka_0$. Then find the value of $k$.

I used a common property of complex numbers which is giving me entire different result. It is as follows.
$$1^k+\alpha^k+(\alpha^2)^k+\cdots+(\alpha^{n-1})^k=0$$ if $k$ in not a multiple of $n$, else $n$; where $\alpha$ is the $n^{th}$ root of unity.

Now from the above fact if can be said that there are some powers of $x$ which are multiple of $7$, hence the required sum will contain coefficients other than $a_0$. Hence I highly doubt the question to be misprinted in my book. Please help whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: The biggest mistake in your MathJax was to have too many small, separate segments. The more math you put together in one pair of dollar signs, the better.

Comment: @arthur ok thanks.

Comment: see my comments following Kavi Rama Murthy's answer.  The *convoluted inference* based on the premise is that $a_7 = 0$ and $a_{14} = 0.$

Comment: I just left an answer in response to Kavi Rama Murthy's editing of his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is an extension of the comments that I left after
Kavi Rama Murthy's answer, and explains why I agree with the OP's analyis
that the problem is *puzzling*.  I also explain why the problem requires the
*convoluted inference* that both $a_7$ and $a_{14}$ are equal to zero.

First of all, I definitely agree with almost all of the analysis in
Kavi Rama Murthy's answer:

- $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \cdots \alpha^6 = 0.$
- In the original presentation of the problem, the variable $k$ is **overloaded.**
  This is easily resolved by re-expressing $f(x)$ as 
  $\displaystyle a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r x^r.$
- For $r \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $r$ is not a multiple of $(7)$ 
  $\displaystyle 1 + (\alpha^r) + (\alpha^r)^2 + (\alpha^r)^3 + (\alpha^r)^4 + (\alpha^r)^5 + (\alpha^r)^6 = 0.$ 
  This is because Kavi Rama Murthy's analysis against $(\alpha)$ also pertains to
  $(\alpha)^r.$ 
  Namely that $(1 - [\alpha^r]) \neq 0$, while 
  $\displaystyle (1 - [\alpha^r]) \times (1 + [\alpha^r] + [\alpha^r]^2 + \cdots + [\alpha^r]^6)
  ~=~ 1 - [\alpha^r]^7 = 0.$

---

However, as explained below, this does not resolve the conflict originally identified by
the original poster.

Let $\displaystyle g(x) = f(x) + f(\alpha x) + f(\alpha^2 x) + \cdots + f(\alpha^6 x)$

$\displaystyle =~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^r) x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^{2r}) x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^{3r}) x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^{4r}) x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^{5r}) x^r $

$\displaystyle +~ a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} a_r (\alpha^{6r}) x^r. $

Therefore,

$$g(x) = 7a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{20} \left[a_r x^r \left(\sum_{s=0}^6 \alpha^{(rs)} \right) \right]. \tag{1}$$

As discussed, as $r$ takes on the values $(1)$ through $(20)$,  
if $r$ is not a multiple of $(7)$, then 
the inner summation for $g(x)$  in equation (1) above, 
$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{s=0}^6 \alpha^{(rs)} \right)$ 
will equal zero.

However, for $r = 7$ or $r = 14$ 
the inner summation for $g(x)$ in equation (1) above, 
$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{s=0}^6 \alpha^{(rs)} \right)$ 
will **instead** equal $(7).$

Therefore

$$g(x) = 7a_0 + 7a_7(x^7) + 7a_{14}(x^{14}). \tag{2}$$

A premise is given that (presumably) for all values of $x, ~g(x) = ka_0$.
I don't see how this premise can be true, for all values of $x$, unless
both $a_7$ and $a_{14}$ are equal to zero.

Therefore, since the constraint
that for all values of $x, ~g(x) = ka_0$
is a **premise**, 
one is forced into the convoluted inference that $0 = a_7$ and $0 = a_{14}$.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: And I also agree that the variable k was overloaded, but I am sure it did not change gist of my query.

Answer (score 1):

I think a silly confusion is caused by the use of bad notations in the question. The $k$ in the definition of $f$ is a dummy variable which has nothing to do with the $k$ in the statement that the sum is $ka_0$. Change $k$ to $i$ or some other variable in the definition of $f(x)$.
Note that $(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha+\alpha^{2}+\cdots+\alpha^{6})=1-\alpha^{7}=0$.  So $1+\alpha+\alpha^{2}+\cdots+\alpha^{6}=0$ Now if you compute the sum you wll get $7a_0$ so $k=7$.

Comment: I am confused by your answer.  I independently came to the exact same conclusion as the OP.  That is, when you compute the 20-th degree polynomial, the coefficients of each term are zero, except for the coefficients that pertain to the terms $x^0, x^7$ and $x^{14}$.  For those terms, I agree with the OP that the coefficients are each $(7)$.  So you have that $7a_0 + 7a_7x^7 + 7a_{14}x^{14} = ka_0$.  I don't see how that you deduce from this that $k = 7$, since that inference would require that $(a_7x^7 + a_{14}x^{14}) = 0,$ for any value of $(x).$

Comment: One interpretation of the problem that would resolve the issue is that since you are given that the final sum equals $ka_0$, for any value of $(x)$, you are forced to conclude that $a_7 = 0$ and $a_{14} = 0$.  A somewhat convoluted inference, but still feasible.  Is this what you are thinking?

Comment: @user2661923 Please read my answer now.

Comment: I just left an answer in response.  In short, I agree that the variable $k$ is overloaded in the original presentation of the question, but still think that the *convoluted inference* is necessary.